Command works fine, but does not in Bash script
EDIT: I'm not really experienced with scripting. I'm in a cyber program, so what is being said has to be used, even if there is a simpler way. Sorry!
Currently, I need to make a script using cat, awk, and grep.
I need to specify variables where a 4-digit date can be used as an argument and a time that can be looked up as an argument as well.
My script is as follows:
date=$1
time=$2
cat $date\_Dealer_schedule.txt | awk -F' ' '{print}' | grep -i $time

The command to run this script:
sh roulette_dealer_finder_by_time.sh 0310 '02:00:00 PM'
What this should output is:
02:00:00 PM     Chyna Mercado   Billy Jones     Cleveland Hanna
What I'm getting:
grep: pm: No such file or directory
If I were to do this without a script and a normal command like:
cat 0310_Dealer_schedule.txt | awk -F' ' '{print}' | grep -i '02:00:00 PM'
Then it works, but I need it to be a script and it is failing.
I'm using GitBash on Windows 11.

I've tried as a normal command and the outcome I want works.
I tried putting that similar structure into a script, but it gives me an error


cat | awk | grep is an anti-pattern. You can do that with awk alone.

Sorry! I should have stated my inexperience at the beginning. Sadly I have to use all 3, even though I agree it seems odd. I'm in a cyber program and the challenge we have asks us to use this type of specific structure. What do you suggest?

Check your script with shellcheck. $time is not quoted.

@KamilCuk Thank you so much! I'll be sure to use that tool from now on.

What on earth is a cyber program?

I’m voting to close this question because the OP didn't use http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag instructs.

agreed, but it might be useful for others as cat | awk | grep is commonly seen in questions

As you are on a course and for educational purposes: It is a quoting issue.
In your command, you grep on grep -i '02:00:00 PM', the whole '02:00:00 PM' as one command line argument.
In your script, you grep on grep -i $time, which resolves to grep -i 02:00:00 pm, or a grep with two command line arguments: 02:00:00 and  pm. The second argument (pm) is used as a file name that needs to be grepped. The file is not there, so that explains the pm: No such file or directory.
Quoting will solve this issue: grep -i "$time" will put the whole string including the space in one argument.
Also read @Diego Torres Milano 's answer about just using grep.

According to the details in your question, you only need grep:
date="$1"
time="$2"
grep -i "^$time" "${date}_Dealer_schedule.txt"

